# RESTful URLs with Spring 3

Tags: model-view-controller, spring, url

How do I get nice-looking URLs in Spring (without a UrlRewriteFilter)? Does Spring 3 have any convenient way of getting nice-looking URLs (like, annotations, or something)?

For example:

/springmvc/**hello** instead of /springmvc/**hello_world.html**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use annotations in our RESTful services implemented by Spring MVC controllers. I'm not sure this is exactly what you are looking for, but our code look like this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/contact")
public class ContactController {
// ...
    @RequestMapping(value = "/info", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody
    ContactInfo getContactInfo() {
        return contactDelegate.getContactInfo();
    }

}
```

The URL for accessing this controller will be http://foo.com/contact/info.

You will need to put `<mvc:annotation-driven />` in your application context XML

Comment: Indeed, I have fixed it. Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 1):

This part of your web.xml determines which requests are routed to the springmvc servlet - any ending .html in the tutorial.

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Change the url-pattern element to you prefer more. Try `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>` to route the requests you're mentioned without any suffix.

Comment: `<url-pattern>/*</url-mapping>` messes up the rest of my app :(

Answer (score 0):

The [ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-coc) is a great way to use convention over configuration to simplify your URL bindings.